# Why do they only have lasers defending the Red Queen chamber?

Tags: resident-evil

Why do they have powerful lasers to kill anything living in the Red Queen chamber? Why do they not have any other weapons to kill?

Comment: To clarify: are you asking about the movie universe or the game universe?

Comment: Well, the lasers seem effective enough. Why would they *need* anything else?

Comment: Movie universe.

Comment: not that effective gnovice they did fail after all

Comment: The laser-grid killed everyone who tried to get through the hallway while it was active. A 100% kill rate is plenty effective. One might argue that the Red Queen's overall system security may not be broad enough, but the lasers did their job just fine.

Comment: Didnt actually think about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The laser grid was a fail safe defense only activated after they hacked her primary defenses.

There is a line in which Caplin says:

> **Caplin:** Some kind of dormant defense mechanism. Opening the door tripped it.
>
> <sub>*Resident Evil*</sub>

It wasn't the only defense, just the only one they didn't bypass, hence the only one we get to see.